# Typesafe Prioritized Rules

Tags: java, validation, generics

I have a small set of validation classes which I have created which have served me well, however now I need to update them to handle prioritized rules.  If a high priority rule is met, then I don't need to run any further validations, as we will just tell the user one single error message instead of adding the entire set of messages to the user.

Here is the set of classes I have:

```
//Rule.java
public interface Rule<T> {
    List<ErrorMessage> validate(T value);
}

//ValidationStrategy.java
public interface ValidationStrategy<T> {
    public List<Rule<? super T>> getRules();
}

//Validator.java
public class Validator<T> implements Rule<T> {

    private List<Rule<? super T>> tests = new ArrayList<Rule<? super T>>();

    public Validator(ValidationStrategy<T> type) {
        this.tests = type.getRules();
    }

    public List<ErrorMessage> validate(T value) {
        List <ErrorMessage> errors = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
            for (Rule<? super T> rule : tests) {
                errors.addAll(rule.check(value));
            }
            return errors;
    }
}
```

I am having some trouble modifying this code to deal with prioritized rules.  Surely there is something out there that I can modify to use instead of bringing in a Rules Engine.

Ideally I'd then be able to create rules like this:

```
private static final Rule<SomeClass> ensureAllFieldsNotBlank = new Rule<SomeClass>(RulePriority.HIGHEST) {

    public List<ErrorMessage> check(SomeClass someClass) {
        List<ErrorMessage> errors = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(someClass.getValue1())
            && StringUtils.isBlank(someClass.getValue2())
            && StringUtils.isBlank(someClass.getValue3())) {
                errors.add("Provide a response for \"" + someClass.getName() + "\"");
        }
        return errors;
    }
};
```

Edit to updated classes:

```
//ValidationStrategy.java
public interface ValidationStrategy<T> {
    public List<Rule<? super T>> getRules(RulePriority rulePriority);
}

//RulePriority.java
public enum RulePriority { HIGHEST, DEFAULT, LOWEST; }

//Validator.java
public class Validator<T> implements Rule<T> {
   private List<Rule<? super T>> tests = new ArrayList<Rule<? super T>>();
   private ValidationStrategy<T> validationStrategy;

   public Validator(ValidationStrategy<T> validationStrategy) {
       this.validationStrategy = validationStrategy;
       for (RulePriority rp : RulePriority.values()) {
           this.tests.addAll(validationStrategy.getRules(rulePriority));
       }
   }

   public List<ErrorMessage> validate(T value) {
       List<ErrorMessage> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (RulePriority rp : RulePriority.values()) {
           for (Rule<? super T> rule : validationStrategy.getRules(rp)) {
               errors.addAll(rule.validate(value));
           }
           if (errors.size() > 0) {
               break;
           }
       }
       return errors;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating an abstract base class to handle rule comparisons:

```
abstract class PrioritizedRule<T> implements Rule<T>, Comparable<PrioritizedRule<T>>{
    public int compareTo(PrioritizedRule<T> other){
        //Implement something that compares rule priorities here.
        //This will probably require support from the constructor, which-
        //since this is abstract- must be Protected.
```

From there, your PrioritizedValidator (which requires PrioritizedRule) will sort() its collection in the start of Validate (if its collection of rules has been modified since the last validate; that's the right time to sort the collection, since we don't want to repeat the sort on every modification if there are consecutive modifications, or do a sort if we don't need to), and the Validate loop should early-out if its list of error messages is non-empty across a transition between rule priorities:

```
public List<ErrorMessage> validate(T value) {
    if(ruleSetModified){
        //be careful: validate becomes unsafe for multithreading here, even if you
        //aren't modifying the ruleset; if this is a problem, implement locking
        //inside here. Multiple threads may try to sort the collection, but not
        //simultaneously. Usually, the set won't be modified, so locking before
        //the test is much, much slower. Synchronizing the method is safest,
        //but carries a tremendous performance penalty
        Collections.sort(rule);
        ruleSetModified = false;
    }
    List <ErrorMessage> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        PrioritizedRule prev = null;
        for (PrioritizedRule<? super T> rule : tests) {
            if(prev != null && prev.compareTo(rule) != 0 && !errors.isEmpty()){
                return errors;
            }
            errors.addAll(rule.check(value));
            prev = rule;
        }
        return errors;
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "...without bringing in a rules engine", but defining rules to sort themselves is probably the most graceful approach. Be careful, though- any two PrioritizedRule-s will have to be comparable to each other, which is why I'm recommending PrioritizedRule be an abstract base instead of an interface, because that's where the compareTo implementation needs to live, for consistency. Your compareTo does not need to be consistent with equals unless you try to keep your collection in a sorted set, which can never end well (PrioritizedRule can't be aware of enough to make itself consistent with equals!), so don't try.

Alternatively, implement a Comparator>, but again, your Rule interface will need to be modified to expose enough information to sort with.

Comment: I like this approach, but I just want to point out that it's easy to make `compareTo()` consistent with `equals()` - just call it! If they're equal return 0, else return anything but.

Comment: This requires that all PrioritizedRule objects have a clear and defined total order- in short, PrioritizedRule, in and of itself, has to have a "tiebreaker" for rules that are of very different types, with very different data. This is generally next to impossible to guarantee. Even using hash codes (if everything overrides hashCode()!) as a tiebreaker isn't necessarily safe- there's always a chance for a collision unless you have a meaningful total order, and as an abstract base class, you don't really have the information to do so safely. Force all Rule objects to have GUIDs as tiebreakers?

Comment: I was thinking of a similar approach, but I need to deal with the situation where I run all rules of a priority prior to returning the error list.  So if I have 2 rules with the highest priority, and 4 with the default priority, and the two highest level rules pass, then I need to validate all 4 rules with the default priority.

Comment: That's slightly more awkward, in the circumstances, but not terrible. All you need to do is also track the previous rule, and only evaluate whether the error list is empty when priority changes. Code snippet under modification, will probably be modified by the time you read this.

Comment: You're correct, I ended up modifying the Validator.  Luckily my rules are set complete at compile time, and they will really only change based upon input; however I can change the rules which are applied at runtime based upon the type of item I am working with.